# Django model for primary and secondary email addresses

Tags: django, model

I have a Django model that has a foreign key back to a user:

```
class Emails(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, unique=True)
    email1 = models.EmailField()
    email2 = models.EmailField()
    email3 = models.EmailField()
```

However, I have two questions:

1. I need way to mark one as the primary email address - is this possible with Django models?
2. Listing out 3 separate fields seems clumsy - is there a more Django-recommended way to store multiple similar values?

**Note**: I'm aware there are a few 3rd party model fields for achieving this, I'm looking for a native approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redesign your model a bit. Style your model like this:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser)
    email = models.EmailField()
    primary = models.BooleanField()
```

This allows for unlimited user emails and having ability to set different parameters per email.

Once user marks one of his email addresses as primary, you can simply first change `primary` field for all his emails to `False` and then the requested one to `True`.

```
user_emails = Email.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(primary=False)
primary_email = Email.objects.get(pk=email_id, user=request.user)
primary_email.primary = True
primary_email.save()
```

Then you'll need to decide how to handle email addresses from the User (or CustomUser) model. You could create a post save signal to store email addresses from User model to this Email model.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't be the approach, it seems heavy-handed.. but I can see the benefits of this method - many thanks.

Comment: There are other way, for example if you use Postgresql with jsonb field. You could get away with only two fields, user and emails (jsonb) fields and then you'd structure json with one key for primary email and another key with list of all user's emails. Or you'd just include jsonb with emails in your User model and use existing User email field for primary email field. I mean, there's plenty of options, but this one is easy to understand and works with all databases. From the performance point of view there isn't really much difference, unless your app is giant like Facebook or Google.

Answer (score 0):

You should store only one email in one object of `Emails` and name it like `UserEmails`. Also, add a field like `is_primary` in this model. So for storing multiple emails, you can create multiple object. This will be a scalable design in case you need to store more than 3 emails in the future.